# RadGrid CommandItemTemplate: accessing controls in ItemCommand event

Tags: c#-4.0, radgrid

Here's my scenario. I have a radgrid that only has 1 editable field (the rest are set to readonly) so that when it's in edit mode the one allowable edit is presented. But when I try to accomplish an insert (add) it only presents the one field for the insert but I need all the others as well.

How do I programmatically switch the readonly attribute during the ItemCommand event without causing a rebind?

Comment: If you tag this with a language, you'll get more responses.

Comment: I'm going a different route. I'll supply the template. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-commanditemtemplate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, here's the solution (without resorting to a custom template). This changes the original state of the column from readonly to an editable one.

```
protected void rgvDepts_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals(RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName))
        {
            GridCommandItem item = e.Item as GridCommandItem;
            GridTableView masterTable = item.OwnerTableView;
            GridBoundColumn gbc = null;
            if (item != null && masterTable != null)
            {                    
                gbc = (GridBoundColumn)masterTable.GetColumn("LIFNR");
                if (gbc != null)
                {
                    gbc.ReadOnly = false;
                    gbc.Visible = true;                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
```